# How is my answer "low quality"?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted an answer as seen in the following Low-quality posts review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12180011

It has received three down-votes, and two reviewers have recommended it for deletion.

I'd like to know what's wrong with my answer here and why it gets downvoted or I'm asked to provide the code to answer the question...

Sure, I could add an additional example how to get the body from the HTTP response... But my answer definitely adds a benefit to the question as it's a modern way to solve the problem in the year 2016.

There are so many bad and low-quality answers and when I try to add something useful to a question which is high-ranked in Google for the readers... The result: Downvotes, bad reviews, etc. It is very, very frustrating. I don't think this will attract any good people to answer questions here in their spare time.

Comment: I cannot judge the technical accuracy of the answer but it is most definitely an answer. It is not link-only since you are saying to use a package and providing how to use it. Note that there are 2 uncorrelated factors: the downvotes, which may be because it is incorrect or poor (I don't know if it is), and the fact that it is in the VLQ Review queue. The latter is definitely wrong.

Comment: You are pointing to an old version of guzzle. There is a comment on the question itself which points to the latest version. That may explain the downvotes, but I have no idea about PHP. Some people think that if there's anything wrong with a post, they should flag it as VLQ.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I agree, you are right. But then some of the downvoters should just have left a comment or have edited my answer in order to correct the link. I thought this is a community here... helping each other, collecting knowledge and information together and save time. Maybe I got the community thought here wrong... I'm disappointed somehow, how it goes here... :-/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I just updated the link to the latest version of Guzzle. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The phrase "excellent guzzle" makes it seem like it might be spam.

Comment: I have no clue why two people thought it was delete worthy and why at least one person thought it was a link only answer.

Comment: To me the answer reads: *"Why reinvent the wheel when someone else already has!" <insert link to library/snippet/whatever it's called in php>* which, to me, seems not very useful. but **not** low quality/in need of deletion.

Comment: To me the answer seems a bit low quality. Mainly because it is a very short answer to a 5 year old question. If some new stuff (guzzle) has arrived since then and you want to mention it, I think you should have started by explaining that. Also you could have given a little more description of the benefit of guzzle instead of just calling it excellent. Also the " reinvent the wheel" seems a little rude to me. And btw - if guzzle is something new compared to the date of the question then someone did "invent the wheel" after the date of the original answers.

Comment: Note also that both of the delete votes you received were from users with fairly low rep (~2600), whereas most of the "looks OK" reviews were from significantly higher-rep users.  That squares with the apparent consensus here that deletion was not an appropriate course of action.  And as others here have observed, the system worked: the answer was not, in fact, deleted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Not really, check out the reviews' times please. When I posted here, 2 recommended deletion and only 1 accepted it. So I expected it to get declined again (like many times before) without any valid reason. So I don't think the system works.

Comment: @Andreas, yes, really.  You keep going on about the timing of the reviews vs. the timing of your question here, but no one else is saying anything that depends on that.  In particular, we are not criticizing the fact that you posed the question here.   We are responding to the question in light of the situation as it ultimately developed.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I believe the two reviewers that recommended deletion are wrong. Your answer provides a link to a resource and, most importantly, explains how to use that resource.

It is clearly not a link only answer, since you provide a code sample on how to use the library.

The answer *is* short, but that does not mean it is very low quality and should be deleted.

Comment: The answer seems incomplete, though, as most post requests will include some parameters. Nothing a quick edit couldn't improve.

Comment: I just added some more information to the answer, it's now longer. ;-)

Answer (score 20):

It seems to me the review mechanism just worked in this case, the sensible majority decided the answer was OK and the minority recommending deletion have therefore been ignored.

It's hard to comment on downvotes since I'm not familiar enough with guzzle to know whether it's an appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: Not really, check out the reviews' times please. When I posted here, 2 recommended deletion and only 1 accepted it. So I expected it to get declined again (like many times before) without any valid reason.

Answer (score 8):

There might be some things going on between the lines here, that you might not realize unless you are familiar with how the SO community thinks.

Judging from the number of up votes, I suspect this might be one of the "canonical duplicates" for the PHP tag(?). The meaning of "canonical duplicate" is that the question is a FAQ, and that this particular post is either regarded as a particularly good question, or that there are particularly good answers present. In other words, the post might be one that the SO community best believes answers a FAQ.

There is such an answer present, which the community regards as great, it has received no less than 620 upvotes which is very rare.

Such posts are regarded a bit more "holy" than others, since they are used as reference when closing down frequently asked questions. It also mean that the post will get far more attention than a regular one.

When you decide to "stomp in" and add something to such a post, the expectations of quality will be far higher. In particular, you have to consider what your answer adds, that those present great answers did not.

It is of course quite possible that you do have something to add - this particular post is 5 years old so there is a chance there might be better methods nowadays.

But if your answer does not add anything that was not already mentioned in the present answers, prepare to get heavily down-voted, even though your answer is technically an acceptable answer as far as SO policies go. As in, there is no reason to delete it.

People might think that you are cluttering up the "canonical duplicate" or that your answer is just a variation of those already present, or that you are posting just to hook up with the attention given in hope of rep farming.

There is no SO policy preventing you from posting to these threads, but it might get frowned on by the community, unless your answer is of similar high quality as those present.

Comment: But that's exactly the point. The up-voted answer on top is just out-dated. There was no package available like guzzle back then. There weren't even namespaces you could use or a package manager like Composer. The way we code changes and the top answer is not the best one in 2016.

Moreover, I had something to add, because no answer before mentioned guzzle. I checked this before. So, honestly, I believe the down-voters have no clue of PHP at all. Things get reviewed by people that are not even able to write a "Hello World" in that particular language. How can they properly review or rate it?

Comment: @Andreas The low-quality review should only focus on removing really bad content - you don't need to new the specific technology to do those reviews. All review queues suffer heavily from "robo-reviewers" who just click without thinking, which might be the case here. None the less, there were 4 reviewers who said there was no reason for delete and so they won. That's why there is a majority vote system to begin with.

Comment: But unfortunately, that's exactly the point. When I started the discussion here, there were 2 suggesting to delete it and only 1 clicked on "approve". It already happened to me that good things were rejected, just because nobody was obviously reading it. That was the reason I was disappointed and annoyed and started the post here. Then suddenly, lots of people approved it.

Comment: @Andreas: _"suddenly, lots of people approved it"_ -- congrats, you have successfully manipulated the Meta effect to your benefit. :) No, your post didn't deserve a vote to delete. But, for better or worse, some people use the moderation tools to express viewpoints not precisely aligned with the intended design of the tools. I would certainly question the value of your answer in context, as explained in the answer above. Especially since it fails to fully address the original question. I wouldn't vote to delete, nor even downvote the post, but I can definitely see why some people would.

Answer (score 3):

As seen here, the general consensus seems that your answer is a valid one. Nevertheless, providing more context, or a more 'real life' example (e.g. member initialization, parameters) in the future might help the community to understand your answer better. It will also help you to gain more reputation :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have also voted that answer down, so I´ll take the chance to explain.

There are several ways to do a POST request in PHP with the functions, methods and tools deeply integrated into PHP.

You could use `curl`, `http_post_fields` or `file_get_contents` in combination with `stream_context_create` like it was pointed out in the answers. Most people obviously recommended `curl` which should get the job done.

Now you come along and throw guzzle into the ring. Well, that thing seems to be well-known around the PHP community, I just heard about it yesterday, but you maneuver yourself in a dependency on guzzle and its functions.

[We all should have heard of how a simple left pad broke the world.](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/) Of course, PHP works different etc. but I, maybe just for myself, don´t like to include external packages, libraries or whatever.

Yeah, that obviously makes me slower when developing, I sometimes may have to reinvent the wheel, but as I am not doing this full-time, I have no big problem with that.

On the other hand building things from the ground enables me to check all of the code, that I have written with my own style, commented like I felt the need to, and see how I got my head around things.

Yes, you can throw a bunch of guzzle in there, hope that it works, read their docs, whatever. But if it breaks, you´ll never know why, have to wait for their bugfixes, trust in their security patches and more.

And for what? Doing a post request which you could do on three different ways with the stuff that is built into Vanilla PHP? I don´t think this is something you should do as a programmer/developer.

We should define ourselves by using built-in ways as often and as good as possible and get our head around problems and how things work instead of linking magical libraries for easy tasks like this.

That´s why I downvoted your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but if you code PHP and don't use 3rdparty packages at all, you have no clue what you are doing at all and are just wasting your time.

When you just heard about guzzle yesterday, you're probably not really into PHP. Maybe you just started, and that's okay. I've been coding PHP for already more than 10 years.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, you just can be into something if you use external packages (for easy tasks, never talked about special applications)... Whatever...

Comment: Says the guy using Wordpress and Magento... lol. I guess you never coded for a really big project with millions of users. Btw. we code our own stuff (mostly native) and use packages when useful. When you don't even have a look at a package and just say "it's a 3rdparty package, so it's shit", then you're not spending your time wisely. That's it.

Comment: You misread what I wrote. Doing POST requests is basic stuff, you shouldn´t use external packages for that. That´s what I wrote, that´s what I mean, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score -6):

That answer is useless. It deserves the down votes it got. You have a link and *one* line of code with no additional context (like how to send parameters with the request as the question specifically asked).

It's not grounds for deletion through the review queue, but that didn't happen.

Answer (score -7):

I think it is a good answer, it is self explanatory and has a good reference to "Guzzle".